# filenotfounderror: [errno 2] no such file or directory: '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/build-tools/34.0.0/aidl'

Tags: python, ubuntu-touch, application-development, android, ubuntu-sdk

I'm using termux app in my android phone. I installed ubuntu in termux. Then i installed python,javac,unzip etc.I also installed NDK, SDk,ANT. Then when i run buildozer android debug command i got this error

```
filenotfounderror: [errno 2] no such file or directory: '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/build-tools/34.0.0/aidl'
```